# Drupal 7 where is user info display php code

Tags: php, drupal-7

[I can not  find user display info  code  in drupal source files plese  help!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Stktg.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find this template in your theme or override it if you are using a subtheme:

**user-profile.tpl.php**

```
$user_profile: An array of profile items. Use render() to print them
```

Réference : https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user-profile.tpl.php/7.x